# How to render a Drawing manager in a Map or a polygon using "@react-google-maps/api"

Tags: react-google-maps, react-google-maps-api

I've been trying to render a `Map` using `@react-google-maps/api": "^2.12.1` in my `react-hook-form": "^7.33.1`. The requirement was to show the map `onClick` of the input, and the user should draw a `polygon` on the Map  using Drawing Manager.

This is my code, I've been trying to get this working from past two days and I'm nowhere near to the solution. I've gone through stack overflow questions but most of the answers were outdated or I couldn't find anything since most of the people are using `react-google-maps` where it has been completely redesigned to `@react-google-maps/api": "^2.12.1`.

The weird thing is the exact code is working in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/drawingmode-null-onoverlaycomplete-scwzz?file=/src/index.js:0-2358). I don't know what I'm
doing wrong here.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { LoadScript, GoogleMap, DrawingManager } from "@react-google-maps/api";

const containerStyle = {
  width: "400px",
  height: "400px",
};

const API_KEY = "";

export default function GoogleMaps() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    drawingMode: "polygon",
  });

  const noDraw = () => {
    setState(function set(prevState) {
      return Object.assign({}, prevState, {
        drawingMode: "maker",
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <LoadScript
        id="script-loader"
        googleMapsApiKey={API_KEY}
        libraries={["drawing"]}
        language="en"
        region="us"
      >
        <GoogleMap
          mapContainerClassName={containerStyle}
          center={{
            lat: 38.9065495,
            lng: -77.0518192,
          }}
          zoom={10}
          version="weekly"
        >
          <DrawingManager
            drawingMode={state.drawingMode}
            options={{
              drawingControl: true,
              drawingControlOptions: {
                drawingModes: ["polygon"],
              },
              polygonOptions: {
                fillColor: `#2196F3`,
                strokeColor: `#2196F3`,
                fillOpacity: 0.5,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                clickable: true,
                editable: true,
                draggable: true,
                zIndex: 1,
              },
            }}
            onPolygonComplete={(poly) => {
              /*const polyArray = poly.getPath().getArray();
              let paths = [];
              polyArray.forEach(function(path) {
                paths.push({ latitude: path.lat(), longitude: path.lng() });
              });
              console.log("onPolygonComplete", polyArray);*/
              console.log("onPolygonComplete", poly);
              noDraw();
            }}
            /*onOverlayComplete={poly => {
              const polyArray = poly.getPath().getArray();
              let paths = [];
              polyArray.forEach(function(path) {
                paths.push({ latitude: path.lat(), longitude: path.lng() });
              });
              console.log("onOverlayComplete", polyArray);
            }}*/
          />
        </GoogleMap>
      </LoadScript>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I know that it has been a while since you have asked this question but I ran into the same issue with the drawing manager and I believe that this is happening due to you using react v18+

The DrawingManager comp is being restricted by your React.StrictMode and it is causing the comp to not work correctly. I found this other post that explains it in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75916790/react-strict-mode-prevents-google-maps-from-rendering-the-geofence-functionality). Basically, you have to use "DrawingManagerF" or get rid of React.StrictMode. Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).