# React strict mode prevents Google maps from rendering the Geofence functionality. I can't draw shapes in the map

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I have a React v18.2 (TS) application where I need to display Google maps to my users. I need the drawing functionality, a.k.a. `geofence` so my users can draw polygon shapes on the map. I have integrated the map using `@react-google-maps/api` v2.18.1 and everything works perfect IF I am **NOT** using `React.StrictMode`. Can someone help me with this issue? I need my `React.StrictMode` turned **ON** and still have the Geofence UI rendered on my maps so my users can use it. How is this related to React strict mode and is there a way to fix this?

This is my `Map` component by the way:

```
import { Polygon, GoogleMap, useLoadScript } from '@react-google-maps/api';

import { DrawingManager } from './drawing-manager';

interface MapsProps {
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
  isStatic: boolean;

  zoom?: number;
  isDrawable?: boolean;
}

interface Shape {
  type: string;
  path: google.maps.LatLngLiteral[];
  radius?: number;
}

const { useRef, useMemo, useState, useCallback } = React;
const __mapMandatoryStyles = { width: '100%', height: '100%' }; // ⌂ Keep it like this and style the parent if needed!
const googleMapsApiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY as string;
const libraries: ('drawing' | 'geometry' | 'localContext' | 'places' | 'visualization')[] = [
  'drawing',
]; // ⌂ Do NOT touch this type! It comes from the '@react-google-maps/api' lib but it's not exported from there.

export const Map = ({
  lat,
  lng,
  isStatic,
  zoom = 15,
  isDrawable = false,
}: MapsProps): JSX.Element | null => {
  const [shapes, setShapes] = useState<Array<Shape>>([]);

  const { isLoaded } = useLoadScript({
    id: 'google-map-script',
    googleMapsApiKey,
    libraries,
  });

  const mapRef = useRef<google.maps.Map | null>(null);
  const drawingManagerRef = useRef(null);

  const handleMapLoad = useCallback((map: google.maps.Map) => {
    if (mapRef?.current) {
      mapRef.current = map;
    }
  }, []);

  const handleDraw = useCallback(
    (shape: Shape) => {
      setShapes([...shapes, shape]);
    },
    [shapes]
  );

  const handleOnPolygonComplete = useCallback(
    (polygon: google.maps.Polygon) => {
      if (polygon.getPath() !== null) {
        const polygonPathArray = polygon.getPath().getArray();

        if (polygonPathArray) {
          const path = polygonPathArray.map(latLngLiteral => {
            return { lat: latLngLiteral.lat(), lng: latLngLiteral.lng() };
          });

          handleDraw({ path, type: 'polygon' });
        }
      }
    },
    [handleDraw]
  );

  const renderShapes = useCallback(
    () =>
      shapes.map((shape, idx): JSX.Element | null =>
        shape.type === 'polygon' ? (
          <Polygon key={idx} path={shape.path.map(latLng => latLng)} />
        ) : null
      ),
    [shapes]
  );

  const getMapOptions = useMemo(
    () => ({
      zoomControl: !isStatic,
      scrollwheel: !isStatic,
      rotateControl: !isStatic,
      clickableIcons: !isStatic,
      mapTypeControl: !isStatic,
      keyboardShortcuts: !isStatic,
      fullscreenControl: !isStatic,
      streetViewControl: !isStatic,
      disableDoubleClickZoom: isStatic,
      isFractionalZoomEnabled: !isStatic,
      gestureHandling: isStatic ? 'none' : 'auto',
    }),
    [isStatic]
  );

  if (isDrawable) {
    return isLoaded ? (
      <GoogleMap
        zoom={zoom}
        center={{ lat, lng }}
        options={getMapOptions}
        mapContainerStyle={__mapMandatoryStyles}
        onLoad={handleMapLoad}
      >
        <DrawingManager
          ref={drawingManagerRef}
          options={{
            drawingControl: true,
            drawingControlOptions: {
              position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
              drawingModes: [google?.maps?.drawing?.OverlayType.POLYGON],
            },
          }}
          onPolygonComplete={handleOnPolygonComplete}
        />

        {renderShapes()}
      </GoogleMap>
    ) : null;
  }

  return isLoaded ? (
    <GoogleMap
      zoom={zoom}
      center={{ lat, lng }}
      options={getMapOptions}
      mapContainerStyle={__mapMandatoryStyles}
    />
  ) : null;
};
```

The `DrawingManager`'s code is:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import {
  DrawingManager as RactGoogleMapsDrawingManager,
  DrawingManagerProps,
} from '@react-google-maps/api';

export const DrawingManager = React.forwardRef<RactGoogleMapsDrawingManager, DrawingManagerProps>(
  (props, ref): JSX.Element => <RactGoogleMapsDrawingManager ref={ref} {...props} />
);

DrawingManager.displayName = 'DrawingManager';
```

Comment: Have you tested this in both production and development? Reacts strict mode does some extra unmounting-remounting and re-running of side effects during development that can sometime cause issues.

Comment: @super Actually I've tested this only in development. I will test it in prod right away! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use `DrawingManagerF` instead of `DrawingManager` for React v18 and Up

It is undocumented but you should use the Components with `F` on its end, in your case, `DrawingManagerF`. Because the old components were not compatible with **React 18**.

Ref: [2.10.0 react@18 support, new functional versions of components](https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/blob/develop/packages/react-google-maps-api/CHANGELOG.md#2100-react18-support-new-functional-versions-of-components)

the `F` letter means `Functional` and using such components would enable you to use `React.Strictmode` without having issues with the `DrawingManager` during development phase.

Since the `React.Strictmode` is only used during development phase, your app should work fine during production phase even when you are using the old `DrawingManager` component. But if you want to use `React.Strictmode` during production, then you should use `DrawingManagerF`. This applies to all other components that you are going to use.

Ref to source code: https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/blob/develop/packages/react-google-maps-api/src/components/drawing/DrawingManager.tsx

With that said, please do note that the public docs are outdated because of build problems as mentioned [here](https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/issues/3064#:%7E:text=docs%20are%20outdated%2C%20due%20to%20broken%20build.).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yrll, amazing, my friend!!! Thank you so much!!! This worked perfect ^_^